# Property passing is not working as expected in Firebase/React Project

Tags: firebase, react-redux, project

Have been working and following this full-stack project created here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a9MZOrFoPTY&list=PLMhAeHCz8S38ryyeMiBPPUnFAiWnoPvWP&index=34

Front-end Repository (To guide you through my errors if u wanna fork):
https://github.com/hidjou/classsed-react-firebase-client

To preface, I have tried asking for help from the author, to be awaited with no reply, which is why I am here to ask for help. To summarize, it is a social-media spin-off of twitter.

My Problem: I am trying to load user information on login/signup, but a few things are happening:
- I get render errors
- properties are not passed correctly; login details are 'undefined' even though marked as required from my 'propTypes'

First off, I have been constantly getting this Type error since the Profile Section video:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'handle' of undefined
- at Scream.render (Scream.js:41)
    at finishClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:15319)
    at updateClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:15274)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:16262)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:20279)
    at workLoop (react-dom.development.js:20320)
```

- the call stack seems to always point to the userActions getUserData() function, which tells me the user props isn't being passed correctly. I have tried changing the code, but since this is a redux error I'm getting, I am led to believe that there is a possibility my firebase console functions are a result of this error (definitely shouldn't be since its only in redux).

My second error has risen when trying to fix the first one. The way I tried fixing the first error was by spreading the state instead of the action.payload in the SET_USER case from userReducer.js. This resulted in this error instead:

```
- Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `user` is marked as required in `LikeButton`, but its value is `undefined`in LikeButton (at ScreamDialog.js:223)
    in ScreamDialog (created by WithStyles(ScreamDialog))
    in WithStyles(ScreamDialog) (created by ConnectFunction)
    in ConnectFunction (at Scream.js:77)
```

I look through the call execution from my code (exactly the same as yours) and I believe this is still a result of not passing the properties 'properly' in my whole system. Although, I am not entirely sure tbh.

Comment: read https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116101/is-it-ok-to-add-solved-to-the-title-of-a-question

Comment: My bad, I am new to posting on StackOverflow, but thank you for the correct conventions. My solution was actually a problem on my backend code: i mispelled a property when passing it in the backend, and fixed my code through that.